# Pandas Not Displaying Value Correctly in Series

Tags: python, pandas, repr

I have a class called `Point()` and I want the print out to be WKT instead of the JSON that is given from the service it gets the point.

The Point class inherits from dict and everything on the class works great except when I display the column in ipython or print the dataframe object.

I've tried the following on the Point class (simplified class):

```
class Point(dict):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
       self._coords = iterable
    def __str__(self):
       return 'Point(%s,%s)' % (self._coords['x'], self._coords['y'])
    def __repr__(self):
       return 'Point(%s,%s)' % (self.x, self.y)
    def _repr_html_(self):
       return self.__str__()
    def _repr_pretty_(self):
       return self.__str__()
```

Example:

```
>>> pt = Point({"x" : -118.15, "y" : 33.80, "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}})
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', pt]], columns=['foo', 'SHAPE'])
>>> df.SHAPE
  foo                                              SHAPE
0   A  {'x': -118.15, 'y': 33.8, 'spatialReference': ...
```

But if I do

```
>>> df.SHAPE[0]
"POINT (-118.15000000000001 33.799999999999997)"
```

Which is the correct desired output.

How do I get the DataFrame to honor my classes **repr** or **str**?

Here is another edit to show very basic issue that I am seeing:

```
class foo(dict):
    def __init__(self, iterable=None, **kwargs):
        if iterable is None:
            iterable = ()
        super(foo, self).__init__(iterable)
        self.update(kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return ",".join(self.keys())
    def __str__(self):
        return ",".join(self.keys())

f = foo({'alpha' : 'b',
    'beta' : 'c'})

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 1, f]], columns=['D', 'F', 'G'])
```

The output for the series 'G' isn't honoring the classes `__repr__` or `__str__`.

Thanks

Comment: can you give us a short example of your class? what is your df composed of? you said it's a dict then it's a DataFrame? Series?

Comment: I added a more robust example

Comment: thanks; you also have a code error for your `_init_` method. I edited it; it missed the self arg. also  your example doesn't generate the output you stated. in Python 3 it's an empty array for `SHAPE` column.

Comment: I really dumbed down my example, but basically I load the keys/values into the object and then I want to do some internal magic and make the ```__repr__``` be the WKT string.

Comment: @stucash I added a simpler example

Comment: just so you know your `Point` Class is throwing on `__repr_pretty()`;  to test you just need to run your pt assignment LOC here. you might want to test your codes if you are going to edit more. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to the github page for Pandas, and found out from the dev team that the pprint function they use does not honor `__str__` or `__repr__` on iterable objects.  Therefore if you inherit from **dict**, you will get the default print from a dictionary.  The basic solution would be to not inherit from dict and just use the default object.

Answer (score 0):

what you have overridden here are the built-in functions for `object`, in python. `pandas` knows nothing about it.

it's correct that when you try to access the item in G in `repl` you get the correct overriden output because that is what you have dictated at object level. but when you try to print `G` itself, you will get the object representation not `str(object)` or `repr(object)`. you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

**repr(object)**

> Return a string containing a printable representation of
>   an object. For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a
>   string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to
>   eval(), otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle
>   brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together
>   with additional information often including the name and address of
>   the object. A class can control what this function returns for its
>   instances by defining a `__repr__()` method.

in short, overriding `__repr__` manipulates what `repr()` returns, it is **not** manipulating object representation.

`foo` in G columns are still objects, they are not `str(foo)`.

Therefore you need to give G the `str(object)` or `repr(object)` as its items.
you are assuming here that when you give objects to `DataFrame`, pandas is auto-translating object representation to `str(object)` or `repr(object)`. it's not in this case.

initial attempt to your desired result you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 1, str(f)]], columns=['D', 'F', 'G'])
print(df)

# output
  D F           G
0 A 1 alpha, beta
```

Comment: So I did some further looking into this on the Panda's github page, it turns out that because I inherit from dict, that the default pprint function will print the key/values.

Comment: I actually think both are correct w.r.t your question here. you could either remove your inheritance from `dict`, or you could do `str(point)` or `repr(point)`; if you override `__str__` and `__repr__` then you essentially override `str(object)` and `repr(object)` as well.